# Javascript isn't counting duplicates properly

Tags: javascript, duplicates, counter

I wrote a javascript to ask the user to input 5 numbers and check for the largest and smallest number. I can get it to display the largest and smallest number sometimes. The main problem is that I need to show an error message when the user inputs the smallest or largest number more than once. When i enter two large numbers in the first two boxes, I get an error message, but if I enter two small numbers, I don't get an error message. Here's my code, I suspect it's my else if, but I'm not totally sure.

EDIT: Sorry all, I forgot to mention that I'm restricted to only using if-else statements. No loops, no arrays. None of that. I know, I know, it's absolutely terrible.

```
function testProgram() {

var largestNum, smallestNum;
var num1, num2, num3, num4, num5;
var smallDupe, largeDupe;

var num1 = document.getElementById("Num1").value;
var num2 = document.getElementById("Num2").value;
var num3 = document.getElementById("Num3").value;
var num4 = document.getElementById("Num4").value;
var num5 = document.getElementById("Num5").value;

num1 = parseFloat(num1);
num2 = parseFloat(num2);
num3 = parseFloat(num3);
num4 = parseFloat(num4);
num5 = parseFloat(num5);

if ((!isNaN(num1)) && (!isNaN(num2)) && (!isNaN(num3)) && (!isNaN(num4)) && (!isNaN(num5))) {

    largestNum = num1;
    smallestNum = num1;
    smallDupe = 0;
    largeDupe = 0;

    if(num2 >= largestNum) {
        if(num2 == largestNum) {
            largeDupe++;
        }
        else if (num2 <= smallestNum) {
            if(num2 == smallestNum) {
                smallDupe++;
            }
                smallestNum = num2;
                smallDupe = 0;
        }   else {
                largestNum = num2;
                largeDupe = 0;
        }
    }
    if(num3 >= largestNum) {
        if(num3 == largestNum) {
            largeDupe++;
        }
        else if (num3 <= smallestNum) {
            if(num3 == smallestNum) {
                smallDupe++;
            }
            smallestNum = num3;
            smallDupe = 0;
        } else {
            largestNum = num3;
            largeDupe = 0;
        }
    }
    if(num4 >= largestNum) {
        if(num4 == largestNum) {
            largeDupe++;
        }
        else if (num4 <= smallestNum) {
            if(num4 == smallestNum) {
                smallDupe++;
            }
            smallestNum = num4;
            smallDupe = 0;
        } else {
            largestNum = num4;
            largeDupe = 0;
        }
    }
    if(num5 >= largestNum) {
        if(num5 == largestNum) {
            largeDupe++;
        }
        else if (num5 <= smallestNum) {
            if(num5 == smallestNum) {
                smallDupe++;
            }
            smallestNum = num5;
            smallDupe = 0;
        } else {
            largestNum = num5;
            largeDupe = 0;
        }
    }

    if (smallDupe > 0 || largeDupe > 0) { 

        // Display an error to the user stating that there are duplicates
        window.alert("The smallest number and/or largest number contains is duplicated.");
        console.log("Error notice");
    }

    // Reference out1 and out2 to the HTML document
    var out1 = document.getElementById("Out1");
    var out2 = document.getElementById("Out2");
    out1.disabled = false;
    out1.value = largestNum;
    out2.disabled = false;
    out2.value = smallestNum;

    } else {

        // Tells the user that their input is invalid and to input five numbers again
        window.alert("Please input five numbers");
        console.log("Error notice");

    }
}
```

Comment: Please learn to use arrays. All that repeated code makes it impossible to follow what you're doing.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean?? Apologies, I'm a newbie

Comment: You could replace all those ifs and else ifs with maybe 5 lines of code if you put the inputs into an array, sorted it, picked the first and last ones as the min and max values, and checked if the second or second-to-last are equal to the min and max values.

Comment: It's an assignment for my javascript class, and we're restricted to only if-else statements. I forgot to mention that

Comment: Put all the numbers into an array, then use a loop instead of duplicating code.

Comment: The problem is that you're setting `smallDupe = 0` after you increment it.

Comment: I figured that could have been the problem. Where would I put smallDupe = 0 if it wasn't actually a dupe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you increment `smallDupe`, you're setting it back to 0. You need to handle the case of the current number being less than the smallest separately from it being equal. Also, if you enter the same number in the first sequence of boxes, it will be a duplicate of both the largest and smallest, and you need to allow this; the simplest way to do this is to use two separate groups of `if/else if` rather than combining them all into one big statement.

```
if(num2 > largestNum) {
    largestNum = num2;
    largeDupe = 0;
} else if (num2 == largestNum) {
    largeDupe++;
}

if (num2 < smallestNum) {
    smallestNum = num2;
    smallDupe = 0;
} else if (num2 == smallestNum) {
    smallDupe++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But one other problem is that if I enter 1, in the first four boxes and different numbers in the next box I don't get an error. What is the reason behind this problem?